# How to make a dynamic layout (like home screen)?

Tags: android, layout, dynamic, homescreen

Cant find any relevant advice while googling, so came here.
So - **what Im trying to make:**

A dynamic gridded layout, where user on long-press in empty space can choose what image to add to that particular place, and that image itself becomes a button with specific function. **If I long click an existing image button, I can move it and it auto snaps to invisible grid.**

Any help on how to accomplish this? Any good tutorials you may know?

Comment: You probably can't find any advice because your search is too specific. Sometimes you have to piece this stuff together. However, I was able to find an example of at least part of what you're trying to in the [Android doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html).

Comment: Android is open source. Look it up yourself, then ask a specific question when you get stuck. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher/+/master/src/com/android/launcher/Launcher.java